# dask and data visualisation

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh, dask

Would anyone be able to let me know whether it is possible to use [dask](https://dask.org/) with python data visualisation python packages such [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) is an extension to Pandas and Numpy (which are already extensively used in Bokeh Python library) and is well suited for big data processing and parallel/distributed computing in Python.
Similair to [Datashader](http://datashader.org/index.html) it can be used to quickly and flexibly preprocess large datasets for visual representation in Bokeh.

So for a stand-alone Bokeh app you would basically need to prepare the visualisation data before you generate your HTML page containing Bokeh plots. In case of Bokeh server app you can have Python callback that periodically processes the big-data and sends an update to the browser. But also in a standalone page you can have AJAX requests or use AjaxDataSource to update the plots periodically.